# Can't Select UICollectionViewcell after Collectionview.reloaddata()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview with three datasources and the items you can select or deselect.

```
switch atIndex {
    case 0:
        print("Fashion Category")
        datasource = categories as! [Category]
        categoryIndex = 0
        //update states for data from Firebase depending on category
        checkCategorieStates(category: "fashion")
        categories = Categories().categories
        headerView.categoryButton.setTitle("Fashion", for: .normal)
    case 1:
        print("Food Category")
        datasource = foodCategories as! [Category]
        categoryIndex = 1
        //update states for data from Firebase depending on category
        checkCategorieStates(category: "food")
        categories = foodCategories
        headerView.categoryButton.setTitle("Food", for: .normal)
    case 2:
        print("Bar Cateogry")
        datasource = barCategories as! [Category]
        categoryIndex = 2
        //update states for data from Firebase depending on category
        checkCategorieStates(category: "drinks")
        categories = barCategories
        headerView.categoryButton.setTitle("Drinks", for: .normal)
    default:
        print("Some other category")
    }
```

I select a category first and then load one datasource and `reloadData()` for the collectionview. 
Then I select several items or deselect them.

```
collectionview.reloadData()
collectionview.isScrollEnabled = true
```

Then I go back. Create an empty datasource and `reloadData()` so it shows no items.

Then I select another category and load another datasource and `reloadData()` for the collectionview to show those items.

But now I can't select the new items anymore.

I reckon the issue lies within reusing UICollectionviewcells, as the more cells I select the first time, the more cells I can't select anymore after `reloadData()`

[image: Example]

Comment: All above collection views is the same one?

Comment: Yes, I basically just empty the Datasource of the same Collectionview, `reloaddata()` and display a button on top of the Collectionview to choose another datasource and reload the same Collectionview with the new Datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the solution in the

`collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

I added the following two lines to deselect the cell for reuse:

```
cell.isSelected = false
collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```